# How can we remove layered navigation filters view page source code in magento 2 category page?

Tags: layered-navigation, magento-2.2.5, seo, meta-tags, category-page

How can we remove the filters applied in category page,ie:
.

It's appending the pipe with filter values in view page source as shown in below-

```
<meta name="description" content=" | Price: $0.00 - $100.00"/>
```

we need to remove the price from its tag.

We have added the SEO mageworx extension for our code base.

Comment: <meta name="description" content=" | Price: $0.00 - $100.00"/> ,we need to remove the price from its tag

Answer (score 0):

In your theme directory find catalog_category_view.xml. and if not existing already create one Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml.
Remove the block by adding this line

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

Your code should look something like the below example.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can also refer to this link
https://www.limely.co.uk/remove-category-filter-from-magento-layered-navigation

Comment: I need to retain it in the category page, but when we apply any filters in it, on click of page source code view, in meta description tag the pipe values, at last, should be removed. How can I achieve it?